# Case Query in Where Clause SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I have the following SQL Query ( I know its probably pretty ugly and inefficient).  I need to be able to query where

```
IF @techID = 0   
Then Technician.Tech_ID > 0
Else @TechID <> 0
Then Technician.Tech_ID = @TechID
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to accomplish this

```
sql = "Select Long_Call.Department,Technician.First_Name,Technician.Last_Name, Clinic_ID,Long_Call.Case_Number,Long_Call.Synopsis," +
                           "Long_Call.Version,Long_Call.Time_On_Call, RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,Long_Call.Call_DateTime,100),7) as Call_Time,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cast(Long_Call.Call_DateTime as date),101) as Call_Date,"+
                           "Call_Tracking.Description as Description from Long_Call,Call_Tracking, " +
                           "Technician where Long_Call.Tech_ID = Technician.Tech_ID and Long_Call.Tracking_ID = Call_Tracking.Tracking_ID and CAST(Long_Call.Call_DateTime as Date)"+
                           "BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate and Long_Call.Time_On_Call >= @Call_Length and Technician.Tech_ID = @TechID and Long_Call.Tracking_ID <> 2 and Long_Call.Tracking_ID <> 3;";
```

Comment: Do you mean `@techID = 0 AND Technician.Tech_ID > 0 OR Technician.Tech_ID = @TechID`?

Comment: I'm looking to query based on if the TechID is 0.  So if it is 0 i want all values greater than it, if it is != 0 then I need only that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this using a composite condition

```
WHERE (@techID = 0 AND Technician.Tech_ID > 0)
OR Technician.Tech_ID = @TechID;
```